# regex to return all text between tags if text contains specific characters (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I am working on a large xml file with units of the following structure:

```
<TrU>
<CrD>16122013, 11:54:13
<CrU>IK
<ChD>16122013, 11:54:13
<ChU>IK
<Seg L=EN-GB>some text in English
<Seg L=RU-RU>some text in Russian
</TrU>
```

I need a regular expression that would find such complete structures only if between the tags `<TrU>` and `</TrU>` occurs any of the following characters:

íèé

The expression to find such structures without the specific character criterium is:
`<TrU>.*?</TrU>`

I modified it into:
`<TrU>.*?[íèé].*?</TrU>`

but it is greedy and finds multiple, neighbourings units at a time usually only 1 of which contains one of the desired characters.

Comment: What about XML Tools > XSL Transformations? You could remove all the nodes that are not `TrU` or are `TrU` but do not contain the chars specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try That:

```
<TrU>(?:(?!<TrU).)*?[íèé].*?<\/TrU>
```

Tested in notepad++

Make sure dot matches newline is checked

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/aTpzpD/3)

Comment: how do I accept? I already upvoted the answer but my reputation is not good enough for my upvote to be shown.